# Java - JUnit Test - ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, unit-testing, arraylist, junit

I wrote a class to find the files walking into directory and subdirectory:

```
public class DirectoryWalker {

    public List<File> walk(String path) {

        File root = new File(path);
        List<File> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        File[] list = root.listFiles();
        resultList.addAll(Arrays.asList(list));
            if (list == null) return null;

        for (File f : list) {
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                walk(f.getAbsolutePath());
                System.out.println("Dir:" + f.getAbsoluteFile());
            } else {
                System.out.println("File:" + f.getAbsoluteFile());
            }
        }
        return resultList;
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to do the test using JUnit:

```
@Test
public void ListOfTheFiles(){

    List<File> result  = directoryWalker.walk("path");
    Assert.assertEquals(Arrays.asList("path\start.fxml"), result);
```

The test complains that:

```
    Expected :java.util.Arrays$ArrayList<[path\start.fxml]> 
Actual :java.util.ArrayList<[path\start.fxml]>
```

How I can test correctly the ArrayList in this case?

Comment: I have trouble believing that this code compiles.  https://ideone.com/rhWwIN.

Comment: The class returned by `Arrays.asList` though also named `ArrayList` is **not to be confused with** the usual `ArrayList`. To be more precise `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList` is different to `java.util.ArrayList`. The first is an **immutable** wrapper around the given array where the second implements what is often called **dynamic arrays**.

Comment: Your problem is that you're comparing a list that contains a `String` with a list that contains a `File`.  A `String` and a `File` will never be equal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest using specialized libraries for assertions, especially not trivial ones like yours.

Try hamcrest:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

then in your test:

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
....

@Test
public void ListOfTheFiles(){

  List<File> result  = directoryWalker.walk("path");
  assertThat(Arrays.asList(new File("path\\start.fxml")), is(result));
```

Update:

you need to add a File instead of a String as the first argument though

Comment: That presumably is not going to fix the issue, though - `assertEquals` should still pass if the lists are indeed equal.

Comment: Sorry i missed that .. the lists of course need to be of same type

Comment: Yeah, that's the actual issue here (i.e. the type of the contained elements) ;)

Comment: No, the lists don't need to be the same type - but you can't expect a list with a `String` to be equal to a list with a `File`.

Comment: Can I suggest that you either remove the bit about hamcrest, or make it clear that is a recommendation not directly related to the problem? Using hamcrest won't fix OP's problem.

Comment: Yeah the hamcrest bit is confusing me. This absolutely is a trivial assertion. hamcrest doesn't simplify anything here, I think

Comment: Yes, although Hamcrest is really good, it's kind of an answer to an entirely different question.  The correct answer to _this_ question is cleverly hidden on the very last line.  I guess if I want to see an answer that says `Assert.assertEquals(Arrays.asList(new File("path\\start.fxml")), result);`, I'll have to write it myself.

Comment: It is the answer to the question with a suggestion that the OP can take advantage of or not.

Comment: @MaciejKowalski, I will try to explain. Aomine's answer has four up-votes because he immediately and thoroughly answers the question. Your answer has two downvotes because you spent 95% of the question making a irrelevant suggestion to use Hamcrest, followed by a single sentence edit that only vaguely answers the question. I hope that helps!

Comment: Even Junit team suggests using third-party matcher libraries for non-basic assertions.. whats wrong with additionally pointing that out? Saying that he missed a slash is good enough for a comment at most.

Comment: Good question! Stack Overflow normally follows a Q/A style format where someone asks a question and someone else answers it while staying mostly on topic. Tangential topics are reserved for comments, or a footnote to your answer, so a recommendation to use Hamcrest would have been a great comment. Again, I think if you compare your answer to Aomine's, you'll see what I'm talking about! Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

as mentioned by  Dawood ibn Kareem within the comments, it seems like you're comparing two lists that contain different type of objects, i.e one is a `List<File>` and the other is a `List<String>` hence why they will never be equal. You'll need to make sure you're either performing the `Assert` on a `List<File>` objects against another `List<File>` objects or a `List<String>` against another `List<String>`  objects but *not* different types.

Also, this string:

```
"path\start.fxml"
```

has to be changed to this:

```
"path\\start.fxml"
```

to escape the literal `\`